# Fetching data to Angular Form Array

Tags: angular

I am just a newbie to angular. When user adds education fields it has the functionality for creating multiple educations with add and remove row. For that I have used FormArray.
It is fetching the data correctly but it is creating an extra nested form.

`

```
/file.ts file
// inside constructor
constructor() {
 this.educationinfo = this.form.group({
      education: this.form.array([this.educationform(this.education) ])
    });
}
// inside ngOnInit 
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params.id;
      this.service.getProfilebyId(this.id).subscribe(res => {
        this.users = res;
        this.users.eduacation = res['education'];
        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
        for (let education of this.users.eduacation) {
          this.addEducation(education);
}
public educationform(education) {
  if (!education) {
    education = {
      institutionName: '',
    level: '',
    yearGraduated: '',
    board: '',
    faculty: ''
    };
  }
  return new FormGroup({
    institutionName: new FormControl(education.institutionName),
    level: new FormControl(education.level),
    yearGraduated: new FormControl(education.yearGraduated),
    board: new FormControl(education.board),
    faculty: new FormControl(education.faculty),
  });
}
addEducation(education): void {
  this.education = this.educationinfo.get('education') as FormArray;
  this.education.push(this.educationform(education));
}

/file.html

 <form [formGroup]="educationinfo" style="padding: 0px 0px 100px 0px!important;">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Educational Information</ng-template>
        <div formArrayName="education" *ngFor="let education of educationinfo.get('education')['controls']; let i= index;">
          <div [formGroupName]="i">
-------</div>
</div>
</form>
```

`

I expect the output to match the length of the array but actually, it creates an extra nested form.

Comment: because you are calling educationform from constructor directly once and from  ngOniti indirectly once through addEducation,hence an extra nested form,suggestion is to remove from ngOniti with some logic.

Comment: @HameedSyed then how to remove it from the ngOnit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you are creating an empty formgroup in your `constructor`, so that is the reason for an "extra" formgroup. Initially don't create an empty formgroup, just create an empty form array:

```ts
constructor(private form: FormBuilder) {
   this.educationinfo = this.form.group({
      education: this.form.array([])
   });
}
```